# How to eliminate the empty space of a dialog/pie chart in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-11

I'm new to JavaFX and encountering this problem.
[Pie chart/dialog with extra dead space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH4Si.png)

My code is

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();

ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
pieChartData.addAll(new PieChart.Data("Win", 45), new PieChart.Data("Loss", 55));
PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
dialog.setGraphic(chart);
```

How can I eliminate this space? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `setGraphic` should be used to set the `Dialog's` icon.  You should be using `getDialogPane().setContent`. If you continue to have an issue after that, try posting an MCVE.  See `https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/` for examples.

Answer (score 0):

`dialog.getDialogPane().setMaxWidth(500);` to set a fixed width of the dialog.
But I haven't figured out why the pie chart has this extra space.

Comment: I explained to you why this is happening. You are using `Dialog.setGraphic` and you should be using `Dialog.getDialogPane().setContent`